# Importing classes from different package/folder in java

Tags: java

[image]
import mentioned below is giving me the error as I am trying to import another class which is in searching.sorted folder. That class' code is mentioned below this code

```
import searching.sorted.BinarySearch;

public class DataStricturesMain {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        BinarySearch bSearch = new BinarySearch();
        int searchElement = 3;
        int foundIndex = bSearch.binarySearch(array,searchElement);

        if(foundIndex == -1){
            System.out.println("Element is not found in the array!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Element:"+ searchElement +" is found at Index: "+foundIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

> BinarySearch Class

```
package searching.sorted;
public class BinarySearch{

    public int binarySearch(int array[], int searchElement){
        int size = array.length;
        int start = 0, end = size-1, mid = size/2, foundIndex = -1;
        boolean found = false;

        while(start != end){
            if(array[mid] == searchElement){
                found = true;
                foundIndex = mid;
                break;
            }
            else if(searchElement > array[mid]){
                start = mid+1;
                mid = (start+end)/2;
            }
            else if(searchElement < array[mid]){
                end = mid-1;
                mid = (start+end)/2;
            }

        }
         return foundIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: "in searching.sorted folder" you mean that literally (as in "it is in a folder called `searching.sorted`") or did you mean `searching/sorted`?

Comment: As @FedericoklezCulloca said - Ideally you would want to have 2 packages "searching" and a child package inside it "sorted".  With that, I tested out your code and it compiles alright, although it doesn't run as you would expect it to, but thats a different question altogether.

Comment: I mean searching/sorted folder. I have also attached the image. Please check it and let me know what change I have to do to make it run

Comment: `src` is the root of your project. `searching` should be inside it, not on the same level.

Comment: Now I am getting this error at running this code: D:\IntelliJIdea_Workspace\DataStructures\src\DataStructuresMain.java
java: package searching.sorted does not exist

Comment: @IshdeepSingh I didn't tell you to rename the folders :) under `src` you put a `searching` folder and under that a `sorted` folder. Inside that folder you put your `BinarySearch.java` file.

Comment: actually it automatically changes to . separated folders when I try to import the java file in my main. Other than that, there is some issue with name BinarySearch. Ii tried changing the name of the file and it worked successfully. Thanks for your insights :)